# Conditionally selecting between two rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like

```
id  | package | env     | key     | value  
int | varchar | varchar | varchar | varchar
```

This is to store configuration, so a row will exist in the database where env is `null`

But the same row could appear again (different id as autoincrement) several times, with different `env` values.

What I want to do is get all the rows `where package = 'something'` and `env is null`, but if a row exists with the same `package` and `key` and `env = 'something_else` then I want to return that row instead of the row where `env is null`.

So, given this data

```
1 | something | null        | title  | a default title
2 | something | testing     | title  | a testing title
3 | something | development | title  | a development title
4 | something | null        | byline | a default byline
5 | another   | null        | title  | another default title
6 | another   | testing     | title  | another testing title
```

If I use package `something` and env `testing` The rows I want back are

```
2 | something | testing     | title  | a testing title
4 | something | null        | byline | a default byline
```

I could run two queries, one the get all rows where `package = something` and `env is null` and then another query where `package = something` and `env = testing` and then merge the second result into the first, but I am hoping there is a way to do this with one query?

Comment: Why `testing` and not `development` or both? And why still the `null` result?

Comment: They are the different environments, `null` = default value, `testing` = a setting override for when we are in the testing environment, `deveopment` = a setting override for when we are in the development environment etc, so. we always want the default settings, and if an override exists for our current environment then we want that instead of the default setting row(aka env is null)

Comment: Think of it in the context of say code igniter, or laravel config, you will have your default config.php that contains a config array, then you will have different folders for your environments that contain their own config.php with any keys that we want to overide if we are in the environment, does that make sense?

Comment: The package is basically the group, e.g. it could be `database` for the database settings (although obviously you wouldn't store them on the database :D) so maybe it could be `gallery` for the gallery settings.

Comment: IMO it would be better to just explicitly define the default values into each environment; it would make your fetch query so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT packages.*
FROM packages
WHERE
  id IN (
  SELECT   coalesce(min(case when env is not null then id end), min(id))
  FROM     packages
  WHERE    (env = 'development' or env is null)
  GROUP BY package, `key`)
```

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8239/12).

In the subquery i'm returning, for every `package, key`,  the minimum id where `env` is not null. If there are no rows where env is not null, with COALESCE I'm returning the minimum id.

Comment: So, if I want a specific environment replacing `is not null` with = 'whatever' should work?

Comment: @Hailwood I updated my answer, you have to specify the condition in the subquery, you could also write it like this: `WHERE package='something' and (env='development' or env is null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `package` = 'something'
    AND ( `env` = 'testing'
        OR `env` IS NULL )
GROUP BY `key`
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: That will always return the default values.

Comment: But the `ORDER BY` clause should take care of it?

Comment: Also, while the default values should, theoretically be first, that cannot be guaranteed.